# How can I change the location of a cursor image?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom cursor interaction point - CSS / JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887403/custom-cursor-interaction-point-css-jquery)

I am changing the image of the mouse pointer using the CSS cursor property ("cursor: url(images/target.png), crosshair;") and have noticed when a user clicks it takes the point from the top left of the image.

How could I change that to a given x & y point within the cursor image?

edit: [Custom cursor interaction point - CSS / JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887403/custom-cursor-interaction-point-css-jquery) gave me the answer (I guess it makes this a duplicate question) - thanks "mu is too short"

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea (dunno if it works): Have you considered using a larger image with some transparent space on the side where you need the offset?

Comment: no I haven't, but wouldn't that make the cursor image further away from the top right?

Comment: sorry made a mistake in my question, it takes it from the top left, not top right, so if you add more transparency to the image, at best the image is in the same position, at worst, the image is further away from the click point.

Comment: Could you post the image incl. a border?